# pprof, No nodes to print

Tags: go, pprof

I have a memory leak in a small program. In order to find the leak, I would like to use `pprof`.

I set it up like this:

```
func main() {
    f, _ := os.Create("my_pprof.pprof")
    pprof.StartCPUProfile(f)

    go func() {
        main2()
    }()

    time.Sleep(1*time.Minute)
    pprof.StopCPUProfile()
    f.Close()
    panic("QUIT")
}
```

When I want to generate the graph, I have the error:

```
$ go tool pprof --pdf my_prog my_pprof.pprof > callgraph.pdf
No nodes to print
```

Why isn't possible to get nodes?

**UPDATE:**
This program will reproduce the issue.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os/exec"
    "time"
    "os"
    "log"
    "runtime/pprof"
)

func pollExec() {
    ticker := time.NewTicker(5 * time.Millisecond)
    quit := make(chan struct{})
    for {
        select {
            case <-ticker.C:
                const command = "cat"
                const arg= "my_project/src/probe/test_pprof.go"
                log.Printf("Execute command: " + command + " " + arg)
                cmd := exec.Command(command, arg)
                out, err := cmd.Output()
                if err != nil {
                    panic("Can't execute command: " + command)
                }
                fmt.Printf("Output: %s\n", out)

            case <-quit:
                ticker.Stop()
                return
        }
    }
}


func main() {
    const pprofFileName = "my_project/src/probe/test.pprof"
    f, err := os.Create(pprofFileName)
    if err != nil {
        panic("Can't open file: " + pprofFileName)
    }
    pprof.StartCPUProfile(f)

    go func() {
        pollExec()
    }()

    time.Sleep(1*time.Minute)
    pprof.StopCPUProfile()
    f.Close()
    panic("QUIT")
}
```

I run it on:

```
$ uname -a
Linux ubuntu 3.13.0-34-generic #60-Ubuntu SMP Wed Aug 13 15:45:27 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

The global context is that I have a very small program pushing information based on a Unix command result. The program size is around 3MB, I have only 40MB ram to run it 24/7. When I leave the example running, the size is growing and growing. I don't know where the leak is and I am very uncomfortable with `go` as this is my first program in this language. 
For the example provided in this post, the memory consumption increased with the time:

```
 PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND                                                                            
16723 paralle+  20   0    6408   1700    816 S   2.0  0.2   0:00.52 test_pprof
After few minutes…
16723 paralle+  20   0    6408   1960    832 S   1.7  0.2   0:04.76 test_pprof
```

Comment: it works for me. Are you sure the prof file is created ok? what's the size of it? you're not checking the error from opening it, any chance you simply can't?

Comment: Maybe your code simply does not enough work? CPU profiling is done by sampling. What happens if you run pprof interactively?

Comment: Are you on Linux? What kernel version? Older kernels (>~9yrs) have problems. https://code.google.com/p/gperftools/issues/detail?id=335

Comment: @Julio is the memory growing when you are not running the cpu profiling?

Comment: @Not_a_Golfer: Yes the memory consumption is growing slowly (from 1876 to 1996 in 30 minutes). Maybe the garbage collector is not flushing when the memory consumption is to slow?

Comment: @Julio you can tune the GC collection threshold. The default is 100% (meaning your process can use up to twice the memory it actually uses), but if you are short on memory, try a value in the range of 10-20%.

Comment: @Julio see http://golang.org/pkg/runtime/debug/#SetGCPercent